# How can I get an RoR image scraping / parsing tool to work w/ sites that require a password for entry?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, parsing, screen-scraping

I recently contracted a dev to build an image scraping tool, similar to Facebook's, and it works really well for any sites that don't need a password for entry, but in the near future I want to expand its utility to work across sites like ideeli.com, fab.com, or other sites that require a password for entry.

Also, I would assume that a user would already be logged in to one of these sites before they attempt to scrape any images from it.

Any ideas for how to go about creating this functionality?

Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the "mechanize" gem (https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize), it's a great tool for automating interactions with websites.

Many sites, however, will ban you if you're caught automating the login process.  I've had trouble with Google in the past.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks a ton for answering and will 100% look into this. Mind if I reach back out if I hit any hurdles or have any more questions?